# Java Recursion - reverse order integers from an array, how it works?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, int, reverse

```
  public static void reversePrint(int[] numbers){
     if(numbers.length == 0) //Base case
         return;  

     int[] a = new int[numbers.length-1];
     for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length-1;i++)
         a[i] = numbers[i+1];

     reversePrint(a);
     System.out.println(numbers[0]); 
  }

 public static void main(String[] args){

   int[] array = new int[]{5,1,34,12,7};
     reversePrint(array);
}


Output:
 7
 12
 34
 1
 5
```

Everything is pretty straightforward,  have a function called reversePrint. When you pass those numbers to the function reversePrint, it takes the first value out, (in this case '5') and then it calls reversePrint again,now with the smaller list.

This Continues until finally we're left with no more numbers, and begins to print them out.

My confusion is in line '10', if the list of numbers is getting less and less by removing the first number each time, how does calling 'System.out.println(numbers[0]);' retrieve numbers that have been removed from the list, and doing so in reverse order?

Comment: where is `numbers[0]` removed?

Comment: As @XtremeBaumer states, the `numbers` array is untouced.  It is only sending the, rather `numbers` becomes the **copied** version of `numbers` from the previous frame shy one element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a scheme to understand the stack of calls in this recursion:

```
reversePrint([5,1,34,12,7]) {
   reversePrint([1,34,12,7]) { // <-- this list IS A COPY, it just ignores the first number
      reversePrint([34,12,7]) {
         reversePrint([12,7]) {
            reversePrint([7]) {
               reversePrint([]);
               print(7); // <-- this is the first number of the current list
            };
            print(12);
         };
         print(34);
      };
      print(1);
   };
   print(5);
};
```

As you can see, the `System.out.println(numbers[0])` is called AFTER propagating the recursion. Note that a new array is created in each call, you don't lose the first number.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up, I completely misunderstood what was happening here.

Comment: Glad to help! Accept the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't actually remove numbers: you copy them from `numbers` to `a` skipping the one in position `0`. That `System.out.println` prints from `numbers`, so the integer at index `0` will still be the same.

Second, the `System.out.println` statement is after the recursive call, so it will be executed after that call returns. So basically, the first `System.out.println` that will execute will be the one in the last call:

```
for ...
reversePrint
|
|    for ...
|    reversePrint
|    |
|    |    for ...
|    |    reversePrint
|    |    |
|    |    |    for ...
|    |    |    reversePrint
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    for ...
|    |    |    |    reversePrint
|    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    |    return
|    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    System.out.println
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    System.out.println
|    |    |
|    |    System.out.println
|    |
|    System.out.println
|
System.out.println
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an exceptionally ineffective implementation of

```
Arrays.asList(5, 1, 34, 12, 7).reverse().forEach(System.out::println)
```

But to answer your question, the reversePrint creates a new array with the first item removed from the array, then prints out the first of the original. The second call will receive [1, 34, 12, 7] because the first has removed the 5, so it will print out the 1.

Comment: @CraigR8806 I was referring to copying the array in every iteration. And even for that, I'd guess `System.arraycopy()` would be the better solution than iteration (although I must admit I've never actually used that).

Answer (score 0):

> how does calling 'System.out.println(numbers[0]);' retrieve numbers that have been removed from the list, and doing so in reverse order?

No numbers have been removed from any array in this code. Each recursive call creates a new array and copies to it all the elements of the current array except of the first element.

Therefore the array passed to the i'th call to `reversePrint()` contains the last n-i+1 elements of the original array.

The recursion ends when `reversePrint()` is called for an empty array. When the last recursive call returns, the next to last call prints `numbers[0]`, which contains the last element of the original array. Then the previous `reversePrint()` prints `numbers[0]`, which contains the next to last element of the original array, and so on...

These are the recursive calls:

```
reversePrint({5,1,34,12,7})
reversePrint({1,34,12,7})
reversePrint({34,12,7})
reversePrint({12,7})
reversePrint({7})
reversePrint({})
```

Now, after each of them returns, `numbers[0]` is printed, so you get

```
7
12
34
1
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps doing it the classic way (rather than making a copy of the array as you do) it would be clearer what is happening.

```
// Private version to pass the offset which increases on each call.
private static void reversePrint(int[] numbers, int from){
    // Base case - stop at end of array.
    if(numbers.length > from) {
        // Print everything else first.
        reversePrint(numbers, from+1);
        // Then the one I am at.
        System.out.println(numbers[from]);
    }
}

public static void reversePrint(int[] numbers){
    reversePrint(numbers, 0);
}

public void test() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
    int[] array = new int[]{5,1,34,12,7};
    reversePrint(array);
}
```